# What PHP web crawler libraries are available?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm looking for some robust, well documented PHP web crawler scripts. Perhaps a PHP port of the Java project - http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

I'm looking for both free and non free versions.

Comment: No crawler is going to do the data scraping, that's something you're going to have to write yourself. And also make sure what you're lifting isn't copyrighted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Additional possible duplicates in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web+crawler+php

Comment: @Gordon - sorry i dont need help for parsing html.

Comment: @Jason If you dont need help parsing HTML, then maybe you should clarify what you are after. The crawled HTML will not magically transform itself into the chunks you deem important. It will have to be parsed. Please update your question to point out what you are looking for or at least what you are not looking for. In addition, please go through the linked search results and see if they contain helpful hints. If you still got questions then, point them out in your question as well. In other words: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scraping and Web crawling framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885760/scraping-and-web-crawling-framework-php/3886030)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) a try.

Excerpt: "Snoopy is a PHP class that simulates a web browser. It automates the task of retrieving web page content and posting forms, for example."

Comment: Sorry man, I know it is a old post but people still read this answer and I downvoted because Snoopy uses Regex to parse HTML and [it's not cool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)...

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte is also a good library compatible with psr-0 standard.

Comment: Since this merge ( https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/pull/397 )  Goutte does not add anythging except `Class Client extends HttpBrowser` from symfony. You can directly use symfony HttpBrowser then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) . It's really simple and useful.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Simple HTML DOM for about 3 years before I discovered [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). It's a lot faster, not working recursively (you can actually dump it) and has a full support for jQuery selectors and methods.

Comment: @Gordon Nope, they are jQuery selectors. From jQuery.com: "Borrowing from CSS 1–3, and then adding its own, jQuery offers a powerful set of tools for matching a set of elements in a document."

Comment: Hmm, okay. They extend on CSS selectors. I guess that's a valid distinction then. Sorry. I rarely see people use anything that's not in the set of CSS selectors when they talk about *jQuery* selectors. They make it sound like jQuery invented them.

Comment: @Gordon yeah, i h8 the "like we invented them" part too :) More info at sizzlejs.com

Answer (score 2):

There is a greate tutorial [here](http://www.ymc.ch/de/blog/webscraping-in-php-with-guzzle-http-and-symfony-domcrawler/) which combines [guzzlehttp](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) and [symfony/dom-crawler](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dom-crawler)

In case the link is lost here is the code you can make use.

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use RuntimeException;

// create http client instance
$client = new GuzzleHttp\ClientClient('http://download.cloud.com/releases');

// create a request
$response = $client->request('/3.0.6/api_3.0.6/TOC_Domain_Admin.html');

// get status code
$status = $response->getStatusCode();

// this is the response body from the requested page (usually html)
//$result = $response->getBody();

// crate crawler instance from body HTML code
$crawler = new Crawler($response->getBody(true));

// apply css selector filter
$filter = $crawler->filter('div.apismallbullet_box');
$result = array();

if (iterator_count($filter) > 1) {

    // iterate over filter results
    foreach ($filter as $i => $content) {

        // create crawler instance for result
        $cralwer = new Crawler($content);
        // extract the values needed
        $result[$i] = array(
            'topic' => $crawler->filter('h5')->text();
            'className' => trim(str_replace(' ', '', $result[$i]['topic'])) . 'Client'
        );
    }
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException('Got empty result processing the dataset!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are thinking about a strong base component than give a try to  http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dom_crawler.html

it is amazing, having a features like css selector.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit old question. A lot of useful libraries came out since then.

Give it a shot to [Crawlzone](https://github.com/crawlzone/crawlzone). It is fast, well documented, asynchronous internet crawling framework with a lot of great features:

- Asynchronous crawling with customizable concurrency.
- Automatically throttling crawling speed based on the load of the website you are crawling.
- If configured, automatically filters out requests forbidden by the robots.txt exclusion standard.
- Straightforward middleware system allows you to append headers, extract data, filter or plug any custom functionality to process the request and response.
- Rich filtering capabilities.
- Ability to set crawling depth
- Easy to extend the core by hooking into the crawling process using events.
- Shut down crawler any time and start over without losing the progress.

Also check out the article I wrote about it:

https://www.codementor.io/zstate/this-is-how-i-crawl-n98s6myxm

Answer (score -3):

Nobody mentioned wget as a good starting point?.

```
wget -r --level=10 -nd http://www.mydomain.com/
```

More @ http://www.erichynds.com/ubuntulinux/automatically-crawl-a-website-looking-for-errors/