# Writing a PHP script to login to a website, navigate to a page, and download a file

Tags: php, authentication, download

I'm trying to write a script to download my VISA payments via the CSV file they provide. I can login and just manually download it, but as a developer anything I do more than once, I want to automate. I want to write a script to login to my bank account, navigate to my visa page, and download the CSV file. The bank is RBC bank, Royal Bank of Canada.

I honestly don't know where to begin. I know HTML/CSS/PHP, how would I utilize my skills to begin this? Where would I start? I want to write this in PHP as its the only language im fluent in and comfortable with.

Comment: If you're able to download it from the RBC website, then you probably could `Curl` it to get the file, in conjunction with an `ultra secure` protected area on your website. What have you tried?

Comment: Resort to a proper mechanize library to solve this problem instead of using vanilla PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize Also, please be aware that your mechanize scripting/testing might cause your bank to become suspicious of your usage pattern and take measures.

Comment: @BjoernRennhak good point on the suspicious note.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't even attempt at building a script to do this. You're potentially `opening up a can of worms` here.

Comment: Ok... this one seems to be `dead in the water`, on to the next log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not duplicated, but you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842371/php-web-crawlers)

> Just give Snoopy a try.
>
> Excerpt: "Snoopy is a PHP class that simulates a web browser. It
>   automates the task of retrieving web page content and posting forms,
>   for example."